# Bigquery Data Export to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, google-bigquery, export

I want to export the results of my query that is the BQ output table into a csv file and load it to a sharepoint location. I can see post related to ingest data from sharepoint to BQ but how about the other way round? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using Cloud Workflows as gluing service.

Essentially the steps would be:

1. use BigQuery and export the file to Cloud Storage
2. use EventArc to observe and once there is a new file launch a Cloud Workflow
3. in Cloud Workflows essentially you will have steps that will post the files binary to a public REST API.

Reach out privately if you want to further discuss some aspects.